# ASP.NET & PDF Files

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iframe

I'm trying to get a pdf file to display a pdf document in my aspx page with an iframe. I'm using the following code:

```
<iframe runat="server" id="testpdf" src="http://localhost:1114/pdfs/3211LD.pdf">
</iframe>
```

When I run the project, I just get an empty frame. However, when I paste the src (http://localhost:1114/pdfs/3211LD.pdf) into the address bar of a browser, it asks me to run/save the file. So I know my virtual directory is set up right.

So why won't it display in an iframe? Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Found out you gotta be running at least IE8 (my VM had an old version) and an up-to-date copy of Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youd be better of with an aspx page binary writing the pdf...

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Set the appropriate ContentType.
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"
        'Get the physical path to the file.
        Dim FilePath As String = MapPath("acrobat.pdf")
        'Write the file directly to the HTTP output stream.
        Response.WriteFile(FilePath)
        Response.End()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When a web broswer displays a PDF file, it is actually using an Adobe Reader plugin to render the contents. I have never seen the Adobe Reader plugin run from inside an iframe. I do not believe it works like that.

Comment: I didn't either, but for the record:

Comment: pnlPDF.Visible = True
            iFrameControl.ID = "PDFVeiwer"
            iFrameControl.Attributes.Add("width", "100%")
            iFrameControl.Attributes.Add("height", "400")
            iFrameControl.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            iFrameControl.Attributes.Add("scrolling", "auto")
            iFrameControl.Attributes.Add("align", "middle")
            iFrameControl.Attributes.Add("frameborder", "1")
            iFrameControl.Attributes.Add("src", "\\MyServer\Letter_UW_3644700.pdf")
            pnlPDF.Controls.Add(iFrameControl)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot totally control what the browser will do, but if you send out a PDF yourself, you can change the Content-disposition header to inline.  Follow @BobTodd's code, but add

```
 Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "inline");
```

to request that the PDF be showed in the page.

Another way is to do it is to rasterize the PDF pages to png and use a `<img>` tags inside of a regular web page.  You could do this with GhostScript.

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft.  We make an [ASP.NET image viewer web control](http://www.atalasoft.com/ajax-image-viewer) and a [PDF Reader add-on](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/pdf-reader)  that converts PDF on the server automatically and displays it in web pages without needing Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the  tag to display a PDF within the page (and/or possibly the embed tag)

Here a question that helps in various ways: [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)